# Should NSURLSession be a weak property

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm investigating a memory leak and from using the Malloc option, it looks like a class that we have has this:

[image]

The class, SessionManager, has

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *urlSession;

- (instancetype)initWithConfiguration(NSURLSessionConfiguration)configuration {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    _urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delgate: self delegateQueue:_sessionQueue];


    }

    return self;
}
```

I'm not sure how to read this, except if I could guess, it'd be the NSURLSession holds onto the SessionManager as well as the SessionManager having a strong reference to NSURLSession.  Should the property for NSURLSession be weak or unowned?

Secondly, if so, what would the reason be for this?

Comment: @Rob can you put that as the answer and I'll mark it closed.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking this question simply because you want to avoid this structure showing up in "debug memory graph" feature, or do you have substantial leaks taking place?

Comment: @Rob Yes I want to avoid this from showing up since it can happen in our sdk.

Comment: You can move the delegate based stuff into a separate object. It’s more of a component-based design with more cleanly delineated responsibilities. And it won’t manifest as a strong reference cycle in the memory graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411530-delegate):

> ### Discussion
>
> This delegate object is responsible for handling
>   authentication challenges, for making caching decisions, and for
>   handling other session-related events. The session object keeps a
>   strong reference to this delegate until your app exits or explicitly
>   invalidates the session. If you do not invalidate the session, your
>   app leaks memory until it exits.

Which basically means exactly what you wrote. You have double-sided strong reference cycle. And as you said you could break it by setting `urlSession` to be `weak` reference. However this may (but not necessary) cause undesirable side effects like immediately losing your `urlSession` after creating it since no object captures the strong reference to it.

I'd advice

- making sure that exactly this part of code really makes some major
  memory leaks (since right now it looks like a simple kind of singleton that should not take too much memory)
- if it really makes memory leak - reconsider your architecture so that you could [invalidate sessions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411538-invalidateandcancel).

P.S.

If your primary goal is to investigate memory leak it would be helpful to take a look at the left panel of Xcode while debugging memory graph to analyze object counters and Xcode's hints (exclamation marks in violet rectangles).

Comment: I tried both methods.  Weak property and invalidating the cache when we are in our general cleanup and both don't show leaks in the memory footprint in Xcode with the debugging memory graph like it does without either of these changes. What is weird is the memory footprint still goes up more if I invalidate the cache instead of having a weak property. Is that because the cache is still around taking up memory?

Comment: Well, it is an interesting question, but unfortunately all memory-related issues on iOS require thorough analyzing both code and instruments' reports. I am afraid I couldn't help you more unless you show how you use your `Session` class _and_ what exactly you see in Xcode while analyzing memory graph.

Comment: If you're interested/need to know the reason and you work on some open-source project you could give a link. Otherwise try to reproduce your problem on a new project and give a link to that one.

Comment: BTW I'd recommend taking a look at this document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW42 and make sure you use delegate's methods correctly and don't leak memory in delegate itself.

Answer (score 2):

As `URLSession` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) says:

> The session object keeps a strong reference to the delegate until your app exits or explicitly invalidates the session.

Because your session manager has a strong reference to the session and the session has a strong reference to its delegate, you have a strong reference cycle, not unresolved until the app terminates or the session is invalidated.

If you want to avoid this, I would not use a weak reference to the `URLSession`. Instead, I'd be inclined to move the `URLSession` delegate methods to a stand-alone delegate object rather than keeping them in your `SessionManager` object. This will avoid the strong reference cycle. It's potentially a cleaner design, too, in keeping with the "single responsibility principle."

But it should be recognized that this doesn't really change the fundamental memory characteristics of the app. The app presumably maintains reference to session manager, which maintains reference to the session, which maintains strong reference to the delegate object. The memory associated with the delegate object will not be released until the session is invalidated. But it avoids the strong reference cycle which may otherwise be cluttering your "debug memory graph" analysis.